# How to install sick_tim package

Tags: ros, laser, ros-hydro, package, sudo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i'm trying to install sick_tim package using the row

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sick_tim
```

unfortunately there is a mistake

```
Unable to locate package ros-hydro-sick_tim
```

in my opinion I make a syntax mistake using the wrong package's name or something similar...please help me to install the package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247364/how-to-install-sick_tim-package/) by [Dornier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28451/dornier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are really on ROS Hydro (and not on Indigo, Jade or Kinetic), then this should work, but you need to be careful with the translation of ROS package names (ie: `sick_tim`) to Debian package names (ie: `.deb`).

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sick-tim
```

Note: `_` in ROS package names gets changed into `-` in Debian package names.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0